# How to pass an image picker image souce from one navigation view to another navigation view?

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator, react-native-image-picker

I am new to react native and I am currently making an image/video capturing app using `ImagePicker` package. I have two separate buttons - one for image capturing and one for video capturing. My problem is that currently my images are being displayed at the same page where my `TouchableOpacity` buttons are, but I need them to be displayed in the next page (`ThirdScreen.js`) by using `StackNavigator`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  PixelRatio,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import Video from 'react-native-video';
import ThirdScreen from './ThirdScreen';
import Help from './app/components/Help';

const util = require('util');

class SecondScreen extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions ={
  header: null,

};
//TODO: Link SecondScreen and PictureTaken together
//Research how to pass props to another component in react-native
render() {
  const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Help onPress = {()=> navigate("HelpSecond")}/>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress = {()=> navigate("Third")}> 
    <Text>Third Screen</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <ImagePickerProject/>
      <VideoPickerProject/>


      </View>
  ); 


}

};

class ImagePickerProject extends Component<{}> {

  state = {

    ImageSource: null,

  };

  selectPhotoTapped(response) {

    console.log('oh hi mark', response.fileName)
    const options = {

      maxWidth: 1000,
      maxHeight: 1000,

      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        file: response.fileName,
      }

    };










    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
      console.log('Response = ', response.fileName);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
      }
      else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      }
      else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      }
      else {
        let source = { uri: response.uri };

        // You can also display the image using data:
        // let source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };

        this.setState({

          ImageSource: source

        });
      }
    });
  }




  render() {

    return (


      <View style={styles.Image}>



{ this.state.ImageSource === null ?  
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.selectPhotoTapped.bind(this)}>
<Text>Photo</Text>
</TouchableOpacity> :
<Image  resizeMode={'cover'}
style={{ width: '100%', height: 400 }}
source={this.state.ImageSource}>
{this.state.file}
</Image>



}






      </View>
    );
  }

};


class VideoPickerProject extends Component<{}> {

  state = {

    ImageSource: null,

  };

  selectPhotoTapped() {

    const options = {


      title: 'Video Picker',
      takePhotoButtonTitle: 'Take Video...',
      mediaType: 'video',
      videoQuality: 'medium',
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true
      }

    };










    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
      }
      else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      }
      else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      }
      else {
        let source = { uri: response.uri };

        // You can also display the image using data:
        // let source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };

        this.setState({

          ImageSource: source

        });
      }
    });
  }





  render() {
    return (


      <View style={styles.Image}>



{ this.state.ImageSource === null ?  
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.selectPhotoTapped.bind(this)}>
<Text>Video</Text>
</TouchableOpacity> :


  <Video style={{ width: '100%', height: 400 }} source={this.state.ImageSource}
  ref={(ref) => {
    this.player = ref
  }}
  rate={1.0}                              // 0 is paused, 1 is normal.
  volume={1.0}                            // 0 is muted, 1 is normal.
  muted={false}                           // Mutes the audio entirely.
  paused={false}                          // Pauses playback entirely.
  resizeMode="cover"                      // Fill the whole screen at aspect ratio.*
  repeat={true}                           // Repeat forever.
  playInBackground={false}                // Audio continues to play when app entering background.
  playWhenInactive={false}                // [iOS] Video continues to play when control or notification center are shown.
  ignoreSilentSwitch={"ignore"}           // [iOS] ignore | obey - When 'ignore', audio will still play with the iOS hard silent switch set to silent. When 'obey', audio will toggle with the switch. When not specified, will inherit audio settings as usual.
  progressUpdateInterval={250.0}          // [iOS] Interval to fire onProgress (default to ~250ms)
  onLoadStart={this.loadStart}            // Callback when video starts to load
  onLoad={this.setDuration}               // Callback when video loads
  onProgress={this.setTime}               // Callback every ~250ms with currentTime
  onEnd={this.onEnd}                      // Callback when playback finishes
  onError={this.videoError}               // Callback when video cannot be loaded
  onBuffer={this.onBuffer}                // Callback when remote video is buffering
  onTimedMetadata={this.onTimedMetadata}/>


}


      </View>
    );
  }

};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({



container: {
flex:1,
justifyContent: 'flex-start',
alignItems: 'center',
backgroundColor: '#1e1f20',
paddingLeft: 60,
paddingRight: 60,
paddingTop: 10,
},
  ImageContainer: {
    borderRadius: 0,
    width: 800,
    height: 800,
    borderColor: '#9B9B9B',
    borderWidth: 1 / PixelRatio.get(),
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#1e1f20',


  },

  button: {
    width: 300,
    height:100,
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'purple',
    alignItems: 'center',

  },

  Image: {

    width: 193, height: 110

  }

});

export default SecondScreen;
```

Comment: Formatting and spelling

Answer (score 0):

Pass its value to other screen through navigation props, something like

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('thirdScreen',{imageData:<uri of image>})
```

and catch that data in other screen

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.imageData
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. It might be a retarded question, but where do I exactly put it in my code? I tried it in several places, but it shows an error: undefined is not an object.